# What's the correct syntax for the Custom Condition of this Task Group I'm trying to create?

Tags: azure-devops

Trying to get a Task to run based on a Custom Condition, but it's not going well.  I am using the Classic Editor, not YAML.

My Task Group has a Parameter `cloudFoundryEnvironment`.  According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#use-a-template-parameter-as-part-of-a-condition) I should be able to specify `endsWith('${{ parameters.cloudFoundryEnvironment }}', '-foo')` and get a `true` result for `pre-foo` and `-foo` values.  I have tried these variations on this theme with zero success:

```
endsWith('${{ parameters.cloudFoundryEnvironment }}', '-foo')

endsWith('${{ parameters['cloudFoundryEnvironment'] }}', '-foo')

endsWith('${{ variables.cloudFoundryEnvironment }}', '-foo')

endsWith(${{ parameters.cloudFoundryEnvironment }}, '-foo')

endsWith('$(cloudFoundryEnvironment)', '-foo')`
```

Note that the value for `cloudFoundryEnvironment` is a *parameter on the Task Group*, **not** a *variable on the pipeline*.

I'm at my wits' end.  Halp.

Comment: A coworker was kind enough to point out that the correct syntax is `endsWith(variables['cloudFoundryEnvironment'], '-foo')` so I'll be posting that as the correct answer (or you can, whoever you are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott replied in the comment,  the correct syntax is `endsWith(variables['cloudFoundryEnvironment'], '-foo')`. See: [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) for more details. Posting here so others can find this answer quickly if they encounter same issue.